# Port Forwarding for a dedicated Server doesn't work

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, windows-firewall, dedicated-server

For some time now I have been trying to get my dedicated server for the game ***Insurgency: Sandstorm*** up and running.

For this I have to specify two ports in the start script. These two ports, in this case `27102` and `27131`, I must now unlock.

I have a ***Speedport Smart 3*** and tried this but unsuccessfully. I have then tried to test a webserver on the port 80. This has worked. Now I do not know why the other ports are not opened. Is this related to the windows firewall? And how do I check if the ports are really open from the outside. I'm running Windows 11.

My Port Forwarding Interface looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnOL4.png).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried but unsuccesfully... You can't add the port forwarding rule to the router, or after you added it, it doesn't work? My answer assumes the latter, but the question is not clear enough.

Comment: @LPChip I added it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Portforwarding is not everything you need in order to make a port accessible to the internet.

Making any port accessible to the internet requires 3 things.

1. A program listening on this port on the computer must be running.
2. The path from the internet to the computer must be defined. This is done by setting port rules in the router.
3. The computer that runs the server, must allow the port in the firewall if present.

I'm pretty sure you have not done step 3. You can test this by simply disabling the firewall and see if it works then. Once tested, enable the firewall again and make a custom rule or allow the program through the firewall. Then test again.

If disabling the firewall does not make a difference, check if you have other firewalls in place. Some virusscanners have a firewall build in as well. If that doesn't work either, then the port forwarding rules are not correct.

You can always try to launch the server and connect from your own computer to that server by connecting to your computer's LAN IP address or if the program allows it, on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). This rules out the port forwarding in the router.

To test a port, you can google for a port tester, and a website will then test if your port is accessible. For example: https://portchecker.co

Comment: Then it must be related to the game server not setting up properly. My web server on port 80 that I had set up had worked.

Comment: That's possible. You must start the server for it to open the ports. Just configuring the server is not enough. It must also be running.